# How to fill color in only a part of the image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, graphics

I am using the following code to fill color in an image in iPhone.

```
- (UIImage *)colorizeImage:(UIImage *)baseImage color:(UIColor *)theColor {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height);

CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);

[theColor set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

But the above code fills the color in the whole image. I just want to feel upper part, say 1/4th of the image. So how to do it?

Comment: I figured it out..

change the line of CGContextFillRect to.
CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, 100));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. change the line of CGContextFillRect to. CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, 100));

Comment: okay answer this issue-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124308/filling-a-portion-of-an-image-with-color

Comment: This is for CGRECT but if image is in other shape then whay to do??