#  how to fill color in image in particular area?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, paint

I want to fill the color in white area for Paint based application 
so please give me suggestion for how to do this work..

[image]

Comment: take a look at the classic flood fill algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Hi,
Here is the [link][1] to get the points of image. means only actual part of the image and eliminate the transparent part. but i am not able to bound the area.


  [1]: http://brownandroidattack.blogspot.com/2010/03/image-transparency-aka-absurd.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Jave for information of floodfill alogrithm

Comment: What tools are you using (language, image processing framework?)

Comment: @misha : I am using JAVA language for Android platform..

Comment: you can see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783204/flood-fill-using-a-stack  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm

Comment: I want to fill it using brush... as usert touch moves... can u help me..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the Solution with Flood fill algoritham

```
private void FloodFill(Bitmap bmp, Point pt, int targetColor, int replacementColor){
Queue<Point> q = new LinkedList<Point>();
q.add(pt);
while (q.size() > 0) {
    Point n = q.poll();
    if (bmp.getPixel(n.x, n.y) != targetColor)
        continue;

    Point w = n, e = new Point(n.x + 1, n.y);
    while ((w.x > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y) == targetColor)) {
        bmp.setPixel(w.x, w.y, replacementColor);
        if ((w.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y - 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y - 1));
        if ((w.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1)
                && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y + 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y + 1));
        w.x--;
    }
    while ((e.x < bmp.getWidth() - 1)
            && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y) == targetColor)) {
        bmp.setPixel(e.x, e.y, replacementColor);

        if ((e.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y - 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y - 1));
        if ((e.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1)
                && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y + 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y + 1));
        e.x++;
    }
}}
```

flood fill in android:

See this [FloodFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm)

Comment: Nice one But If i just add this algorithm to My Android app if i call the function FloodFill(with respective attributes)  then will it be works ? And what should i have to give as attribute Point in this function ?

Comment: thanks @Hardik, its really a nicely written algorithm. but for android phone it seem to be very slow. do you know any other way for flood filling?

Comment: can anyone explain how to provide the targetcolor and replacement color and in which format

Comment: this Answer is not defined properly. You have to show the full implementation that how to use it in Android App, which works perfectly if apply.

Comment: How can we use this floodfill algorithm in case of bitmap image?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick application using Python and OpenCV (should be available on Android if you try hard enough):

```
"""Flood fills with random color on click.  Press `q' to exit."""
import cv
import sys
import random

TOL = 10
TOL_BGR = (TOL, TOL, TOL, 0)

def click(event,x,y,flags,im):
    if event == cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        b,g,r = [ random.random() * 255 for i in range(3) ]
        cv.FloodFill(im, (x,y), (b,g,r,0), TOL_BGR, TOL_BGR)

im = cv.LoadImage(sys.argv[1], cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
cv.NamedWindow(__file__, 1)
cv.SetMouseCallback(__file__, click, im)
while True:
    cv.ShowImage(__file__, im)
    key = cv.WaitKey(33)
    if chr(key & 0xff) == 'q':
        break
cv.SaveImage('floodfill.png', im)
```

Every time the user clicks an image, the application flood-fills using the click location as a seed.  The color is picked randomly.  You can change the tolerances by modifying the value of TOL (or TOL_BGR).  Here's the result after a couple of clicks:

[image]

The general algorithm is the same regardless of what technology you use.

Comment: could you please send the source code, because i cant understood this part

Comment: No, I will not email you teh codez.  The source code is in my answer, anyway.  If you don't understand anything, then please read the documentation for the relevant functions -- it is readily available.

Comment: If I use SVG instead of normal image what will be the approach?

Answer (score 0):

1)Have the Split up image for each color portion separately with same size as actual image and other portion are transparent.
2)Have the complete image with each portion painting in different color in ur drawable folder - this is just reference image.

3) Add the all split up images in frame layout and set all split up invisible initially and set visible to actual image only

4) Hot code the color for each split up from ur reference image (step2) for Eg handSplitImageColor = green;

4) Set the listener for frame layout find out the x and y position and pass the x and y position to ur reference image (step 2) and find out the color in that particular location and match the color with step 4 and fill the particular in that image and set the visibility true for that split up image. So only that portion will get filled by color since other portion are transparent.

These are the steps i used for one of my same type of problems.

But I don't think this is the better solution but it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

after lot of searching, i came up with the following.
It is fast and efficient

```
private void myFloodFillMethod(Point node,int targetColor, int fillColor) {
    if (targetColor != fillColor) {
        Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        do {
            int x = node.x;
            int y = node.y;

            while (x > 0 && getPixelColorFromArr(x - 1, y) == targetColor) {
                x--;                }
            boolean spanUp = false;
            boolean spanDown = false;

            while (x < width && checkEquality(getPixelColorFromArr(x, y),targetColor)) {
                setPixelColorFromArr(x, y, fillColor);
                if (!spanUp && y > 0
                        && checkEquality(getPixelColorFromArr(x, y - 1),targetColor)) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                    spanUp = true;
                } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                        && !checkEquality(getPixelColorFromArr(x, y - 1),targetColor)) {
                    spanUp = false;
                }
                if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && checkEquality(getPixelColorFromArr(x, y + 1), targetColor)) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                    spanDown = true;
                } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && !checkEquality(getPixelColorFromArr(x, y + 1),targetColor)) {
                    spanDown = false;
                }
                x++;
            }

        } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
    }

}

private boolean checkEquality(int pixelColorFromArr, int targetColor) {
    return pixelColorFromArr == targetColor;
}

void fillColorInImage(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor, int replacementColor){

    if(targetColor ==  replacementColor) return;

    width = image.getWidth();
    height = image.getHeight();

    pixelArr = new int[width*height];

    image.getPixels(pixelArr,0,width,0,0,width,height);
    myFloodFillMethod(node,targetColor,replacementColor);

    image.setPixels(pixelArr,0,width,0,0,width,height);

}
```

how to call:

```
fillColorInImage(bmp, point, targetColor, replacementColor);
```

where

`bmp` is the bitmap of image(extract form the image view)

`point` is Point(x,y) where user has tapped:get it from `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`

`targetColor` is the color of the point: get it from `bitmap.getPixel()`

`replacementColor` is the color you want to replace it to