# Coloring with flood-fill method

Tags: java, android, image, flood-fill

I use a flood-fill method for a simple coloring game project on Android. There is a coloring problem. I will try to explain my problem on the following images.

This is an empty image:

[image]

When I start to paint anywhere in the head, I can paint everywhere in the image like this:
[image]

But if I start to paint outside of the head, I cannot paint anywhere in the image as follows.
[image]

If I firstly paint outside of the head, I cannot paint anywhere (eyes, skin, nostrils, ...)

Do you know what is the problem?

The method which I used : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968484/915626

Thanks!

Comment: post your code what you have done

Comment: Without seeing the code, it is tough to guess... However, I'd think that the "outside" area overlaps the "inside" areas, and you don't take into count the situation that the area is "painted around"...

Comment: If I paint the skin first, I can still paint the eyes. I guess this is also an overlapping. But, if I paint the outside of the head first, then I cannot paint anything in the head.

Comment: I used exactly the same code in the link which I gave above.

Comment: i used the exact code in that link..and it works perfectly fine. maybe there is something else error in your code. try to post some more code.

Comment: Yes you are right, I found the problem. I had incorrectly selected a color of a constant coordinate as the target color instead of that of the coordinate pointed by mouse pointer.