# flood fill coloring on android

Tags: android, colors, flood-fill

i just try to use FloodFill class and i found strange problem with coloring.

Lets start with code:

```
public class FloodFill {
public void floodFill(Bitmap  image, Point node, int targetColor,
        int replacementColor) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int target = targetColor;
    int replacement = replacementColor;
    if (target != replacement) {
        Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
        do {
            int x = node.x;
            int y = node.y;
            while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                x--;
            }
            boolean spanUp = false;
            boolean spanDown = false;
            while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                    spanUp = true;
                } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                        && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                    spanUp = false;
                }
                if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                    spanDown = true;
                } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                    spanDown = false;
                }
                x++;
            }
        } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
    }
}
}
```

And method where i use FloodFill:

```
public void colorize()
    {
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        view.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                int x = (int)event.getX();
                int y = (int)event.getY();

                ...

                flood.floodFill(bmp, new Point(x, y), bmp.getPixel(x, y), color);
                view.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                ...
            }
        });
    }
```

If i try to use standard android color f.g: Color.RED and Color.GREEN, everything works fine. I can replace f.g red with green its works, but if i try to use custom color like this: f.g. Color.rgb(34, 198, 67) i get single point colored instead of filled shape.

Can You help me to find a solution for this problem?

Edit1:

I spoted something interesting. Custom colors seems to be different values on some pixels but i dont know why if i using flood-fill.

Comment: can you please share the full implementation of this code, I need it for my project please.

Comment: Hi @ZiaUrRahman, sorry but this is not possible. This code was written for commercial product and is owned by company I used to work for. I don't have access to this project any more. I hope you can find a way to make it work in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't mean to give the full project, but just want that you please just utilize the colorize() in a MainActivity, I wana see how it works (fill the area by touching different bounds) ... then rest of my project, I will do according to my requirement. Hope you help me in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman To be honest I can't remember how I used this code, but I'm pretty sure that I found it here: [How to use flood fill algorithm in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968412/how-to-use-flood-fill-algorithm-in-android)

There is something about views and activities. It'll by 3 years now I'm not working on android so there probably change a lot. As I remember this code was tested on android 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Bitmap where i used floodfill was RGB_565. I just convert it to ARGB_8888 and everything work fine.