# How to resize the bitmap image in this flood Fill algorithm code and custom view

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and I am trying to implement a flood fill algorithm to colorize selected part in the image as a color book app.
I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968412/how-to-use-flood-fill-algorithm-in-android) which provides full working code (but slow) for the algorithm. and also provide **QueueLinearFloodFiller** which is way faster.
The problem is that The custom MyView class is added to Relativelayout to show the bitmap that will be colored but the image is out of the view like this

I want to wrap it to fill the view and take its size like in wrap_content

[image]

I have tried to use this code to resize it

```
dashBoard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
    int width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int hight = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    myView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,hight));
    dashBoard.addView(myView);
```

but it didn't work.

here is the full code and the XML

```
public class UnicornColorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout dashBoard;
private MyView myView;
public ImageView image;

Button b_red, b_blue, b_green, b_orange, b_clear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new MyView(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_unicorn_color);
    findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);

    b_red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_red);
    b_blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_blue);
    b_green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_green);
    b_orange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_orange);

    b_red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF0000);
        }
    });

    b_blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFF0000FF);
        }
    });

    b_green.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFF00FF00);
        }
    });

    b_orange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF9900);
        }
    });

    dashBoard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
    int width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int hight = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    myView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,hight));
    dashBoard.addView(myView);
}

public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    public Canvas canvas;

    //Bitmap mutableBitmap ;
    public MyView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.unicorn_2).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        //Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 60, 60 , false);
        this.path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p1.x = (int) x;
                p1.y = (int) y;
                final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
                new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
                invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    public void changePaintColor(int color){
        this.paint.setColor(color);
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

// flood fill
public class FloodFill {

    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor, int replacementColor) {

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;

        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;
                }

                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < (height - 1) && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }

            } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawingLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="542dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashBoard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b_red"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_red"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_green"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_red"
    android:background="#00FF00" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_blue"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_green"
    android:background="#0000FF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_orange"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_blue"
    android:background="#FF9900" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Clear" />
```

Can Someone please help me to fix this