# align an imageview on top of imagemap

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a clickable imagemap to indicate positions on a body.
On clicking an area, an additional image will be shown indicating that area was clicked. 
I have that working, but the additional image does not align correctly with my map.
To see the problem I modified my view to show all images at once, in stead of only when clicked at.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<RelativeLayout     
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ctc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.sbar"
 android:id="@+id/my_frame"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <com.example.sbar.ImageMap
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/sbar"
    ctc:map="sbar"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/map"
    android:src="@drawable/l1"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/r1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/r1"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the result is like this:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should try the flood fill algorithm rather than superimposing images  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801047/how-to-fill-color-in-image-in-particular-area -

Comment: Thank you. I rather keep the images tough, as I need them as part of a html email and I need to remember which area was selected. I planned to do the following on clicking on an area: 
 name = mImageMap.getName(id);
 if (name.equals("L1")){
  l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

Comment: I got it working now, Needed to replace android:src="@drawable/l1" by  android:background="@drawable/l1" ! The images align now perfectly.