# Dynamically coloring part of a vectorDrawable in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, colors, drawable

I'm trying to find an optimal way to color dynamically parts of an image in my Android application. I have been reading about `vectorDrawables` and color specific paths of them, but I didn't find any good example or way about how to do it efficiently.

My idea is find a way to draw the next dummy, coloring with red the specific "muscles" that are worked when you do an specific exercise:

[image]

How can I achieve this using `vectorDrawable` or any another way?

Comment: one way to pull this off is to have two images one fully red, and one fully grey on top of each other, and to use masking on the red one to only show parts of it, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614542/maskingcrop-image-in-frame

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801047/how-to-fill-color-in-image-in-particular-area

Comment: This can be achieved by applied a different theme to the drawable. That will need one theme for every case, which is not very efficient/easy way. Better would be to have every part as a separate drawable and just tint the needed ones.