# Color selected part of image taken from camera on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, image-processing

My requirement is to fill specific color on specific area of an image. But the image should be an image taken from iphone camera or photo gallery. For example, I could take a picture of me with a blue shirt, the app should allow me to change the color of the shirt to red.
Exactly the functionality of "Paint bucket" tool of the photoshop.

I found couple of approaches

1) Using MASKS with prepared images

[color selected part of image on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788669/color-selected-part-of-image-on-touch)

[Fill color on specific portion of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061769/fill-color-on-specific-portion-of-image)

Scanline Flood Fill Algorithm
 https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

2) Using GLPaint (Actually this is NOT the solution I am running after)

My question is,

Is it possible to color specific area of a image WITH OUT having MASKS or with generating masks for the image on run time?

Scanline Flood Fill Algorithm does that in to a certain level. But when it comes to real time images(like selfie images) it wont work correctly?